# How can aircraft land on choppy water?

Tags: landing, pilot-technique

What plane can land the slowest on the water? What plane can land on the choppiest water? Is there a way to land between the waves?

Comment: The answer to all 3 of those depends on the winds, in the end.

Comment: And timing... That's how the FAA suggests you do it anyway. Are you talking about seaplanes, or crashing?

Comment: The Grumman Albatross can operate in 4-5-foot swells. Is that the sort of thing you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how bad is the sea state, but the general technique for seaplanes is to [land parallel to the swell, preferably on top of a wave](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/media/faa-h-8083-23-4.pdf):

> When landing on a swell system with large, widely
>   spaced crests more than four times the length of the
>   floats, the best landing heading parallels the crests and
>   has the most favorable headwind component. In this
>   situation, it makes little difference whether touchdown
>   is on top of the crest or in the trough.

If forced to land against the swell, it is recommended to land on the backside of the wave:

> If crosswind limits would be exceeded by landing parallel to the swell, landing perpendicular to the swell
>   might be the only option. Landing in closely spaced
>   swells less than four times the length of the floats
>   should be considered an emergency procedure only,
>   since damage or loss of the seaplane can be expected.
>   If the distance between crests is less than half the length
>   of the floats, the touchdown may be smooth, since the
>   floats will always be supported by at least two waves,
>   but expect severe motion and forces as the seaplane
>   slows.
>   A downswell landing on the back of the swell is preferred.

Comment: Could the anonymous downvoter explain if their issue is with me or the FAA handbook's recommendations?

Comment: Oh, now you're having issues too? It wasn't me, but there may be an additional procedure for "chop". Your answer is swell, though.

Comment: It may be "into the wind" with light chop, parallel with larger swell, generally not recommended in rough seas as a wing tip may catch etc.  What plane can land in the choppiest water may have a lot of opinions.  It is tough to find a good answer to a vague question.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni yes, I breezed right through it.

Answer (score -4):

How high are the waves? Timing into the wind, proper flare and try not to capsized I reckon. Never sideways to the waves.

Comment: *"Never sideways to the waves"* I assume this means not parallel to the swell? I disagree, this is in fact the [preferred direction to land a seaplane](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/seaplane_handbook/media/faa-h-8083-23-4.pdf).

Comment: I should have said never sideways into the leading edge of the waves... Apologies